# Date time conversion for OPC timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, csv, datetime

First of all I'm not a C#.
I'm reading a .csv file exported by a OPC Server and I have to export the data in more readable format.

The file looks like below:

```
*Type,Value,Time Stamp,Refresh Time,Quality
03,294,2016-04-19T10:57:52.003+03:00,10000,192
03,294,2016-04-19T10:58:02.003+03:00,10000,192
03,294,2016-04-19T10:58:12.003+03:00,10000,192*
```

I read the csv file using FileHelpers library and I have to export just the Value and Time Stamp.
The problem is that I have hard time formating the Time Stamp into more readable DateTime format. I would to present in the following format:
DD/MM/YY hh:mm
19/04/2016 10:57

How can I get rid of seconds and .003+03?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options here,

Option 1: Read as Datetime and export again using ToString

```
var newDate = DateTime.Parse("INPUT COLUMN").ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");
```

Option 2: Parse as string and get rid of it

```
var newDate = new Regex(@"\d+\.[^,]+").Replace("WHOLE ROW HERE","");
```

Comment: Using the first option:
var newDate = DateTime.Parse(record.TimeStamp).ToString("DD/MM/YY hh:mm");Console.Write(newDate+" ");


I get the following result in console:
DD04/YY 10:57
DD/04/YY 10:58
DD/04/YY 10:58

So the month is ok but year and day are not.

Comment: @Leon Yes sorry my bad, please check the edited answer, the case was wrong, It should have been dd/MM/yy

Comment: @Leon this will work.  var newDate = DateTime.Parse("record.TimeStamp").ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");

Comment: @ MoustafaS Thanks. I never thought that it would be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyy hh:mm") // or any DateTime.
```